# cannot suddenly ping to a certain host even though it worked before and it works vise versa

Tags: centos, networking, ping, drbd

I cannot ping only to a one certain host `$B` from an only certain host `$A`, even though it worked before.

- [A] `ping $B` --> destination host unreachable
- [B] `ping $A` works.
- [C] `ping $B` works.
- [A] `traceroute $B` result:

  ```
  1. $B 3005.339 ms !H 3005.277 ms !H 3005.250 ms !H
  ```

Host `$B` has 2 ethernet interfaces (`eth0` - by default, `eth1` - for `drbd`, `DEFROUTE=no` for `eth1`), and used as primary node. `eth0` and `eth1` are located in different subnets.

Both hosts A and B, C are located in a same subnet and have CentOS 7 installed.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: `A$ ping B` --> `destination host unreachable`. `C$ ping B` --> works. `B$ ping A` --> works. `B$ ssh A` --> doesn't work. `B$ ssh C` --> works. Correct? Are you using hostnames or IP addresses? What does `traceroute` say?

Comment: @Philippos, [$A] traceroute $B. result: 1. $B 3005.339 ms !H  3005.277 ms !H  3005.250 ms !H

Comment: @Philippos, exactly

Comment: @y47999 please add those updates to your question, where they can be easily read

Comment: Try 'sudo tcpdump -i eth0 icmp' on host A while pinging host B, to see if there is a helpful icmp reply from B. Can you provide the output of 'route -n' from host A and B?

Comment: It's still unanswered, whether you are using hostnames or IP addresses

Comment: @gerhardd. while pinging from $A to $B `tcpdump -vv -i eth0 icmp`: ```tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel```

Comment: I want to mention this doesn't work if on host $B drbd cluster is in primary state, drbd is on eth1

Comment: It would help if `$A` and `$B` weren't obfuscated, and if for each system A, B, C you wrote the network state by using these commands: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`.

Comment: '0 packets captured 0 packets received by filter 0 packets dropped by kernel' You mean, you don't even see the outgoing icmp (ping) packets? Please post 'route -n' from Host A and B.